# How to replace regex patterns with the length of the matched pattern?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to analyse some databases which are not well structured.
So I try to complete the following code to analyse it by adding of the number of numeric characters.

```
TRACA2 <- data.frame("CAT"=rep("GEN1", 20), "ARTICLE"=rep(c("PRODUCT  V29000655B","PRODUCT  V29000658A","T172560088"),c(10,2,8)), "SERIAL"=rep(c("172560082","T172560088","PRODUCT  V29000658A"),c(10,2,8)), "LIGNE"="ISG3B51",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)
analyseData <- function (x, na.rm=FALSE) {
    remplacement <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) (if_else(is.na(sapply(x,as.numeric)),gsub("[0-9\\.]+","",x),as.character(paste0("<",nchar(as.numeric(x)),">"))))
    x <- x %>% mutate_all(funs(recode=remplacement)) %>% select(ends_with("recode")) %>% group_by_all() %>% summarise(nb = n())
    return (as.data.frame(x))
}
analyseData(TRACA2)

#  CAT_recode ARTICLE_recode SERIAL_recode LIGNE_recode nb
#1        GEN    PRODUCT  VA             T         ISGB  2
#2        GEN    PRODUCT  VB           <9>         ISGB 10
#3        GEN              T   PRODUCT  VA         ISGB  8
```

Now I want to get the following

```
#     CAT_recode    ARTICLE_recode    SERIAL_recode       LIGNE_recode nb
#1        GEN<1>    PRODUCT  V<8>A             T<9>         ISG<1>B<2>  2
#2        GEN<1>    PRODUCT  V<8>B              <9>         ISG<1>B<2> 10
#3        GEN<1>              T<9>   PRODUCT  V<8>A         ISG<1>B<2>  8
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

`str_replace_all` has an argument, `replacement`, that can take a function; it'll then run that function over each match, and insert the result in in place of the original match.

Should be exactly what you need!

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

TRACA2 %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(recode = str_replace_all(
      .,
      "[0-9\\.]+",
      function(x) paste0("<", nchar(x), ">")
    )
  )) %>% 
  select(ends_with("recode")) %>% 
  group_by_all() %>% 
  summarise(nb = n())
```

PS It looks like `funs` is soft-deprecated; to use `list` instead, write the second line like this:

```r
mutate_all(list(recode = ~ str_replace_all(
```